# How to encrypt web.config properly?

Tags: asp.net

I think I might need to have connectionstring in my web.config as well as use this:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApp" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

The error is: "A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object."

Can I use "-site" somehow to specify the exact location of my web.config? Could someone provide an example for this case?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" password="somepassword" userName="someusername" /> 
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken" />
            </assemblies>
    </compilation>        
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's a more detailed example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Passwords just used for verification should not be encrypted, they need to be hashed with a password hashing method that includes substantial time (~100ms of CPU time).